# Bloc provider above OverlayEntry flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having some problems with my flutter app. I am trying to add an overlay like this in the photo below:

[image]

And it works just fine, I am able to open it on long press and close it on tap everywhere else on the screen.
The problem is that those two buttons - delete and edit - should call a bloc method that then do all the logic, but I do not have a bloc provider above the OverlayEntry. This is the error:

````
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<BrowseBloc> above this _OverlayEntryWidget Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that _OverlayEntryWidget is under your MultiProvider/Provider<BrowseBloc>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
````

I've already encountered this error but this time I'm in a bit of trouble because I'm working with an overlay and not a widget.

This is my code:

```
late OverlayEntry _popupDialog;

class ExpenseCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExpenseCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppBloc, AppState>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.theme != current.theme,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () {
                _popupDialog = _createOverlay(expense);
                Overlay.of(context)?.insert(_popupDialog);
              },
              child: Card(
                ...some widgets
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(height: 0),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

OverlayEntry _createOverlay(Expenses e) {
  return OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _popupDialog.remove(),
      child: AnimatedDialog(
        child: _createPopupContent(context, e),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _createPopupContent(BuildContext context, Expenses e) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: LocalCache.getActiveTheme() == ThemeMode.dark ? darkColorScheme.surface : lightColorScheme.surface,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              ...some other widgets
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 256,
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _popupDialog.remove();
                    // This is where the error is been thrown
                    context.read<BrowseBloc>().add(SetTransactionToEdit(e));
                    showBottomModalSheet(
                      context,
                      dateExpense: e.dateExpense,
                      total: e.total,
                      transactionToEdit: e,
                    );
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).edit), const Spacer(), const Icon(Icons.edit)],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(height: 0),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _popupDialog.remove();
                    // This is where the error is been thrown
                    context.read<BrowseBloc>().add(DeleteExpense(e.id!, e.isExpense));
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).delete), const Spacer(), const Icon(Unicons.delete)],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I add the bloc provider above my OverlayEntry? Is this the best course of action?

Thank you to everyone that can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution starting from the answer of Olga P, but changing one thing. I use the BlocProvider.value but I am passing as an argument to the method the context and not the bloc itself. This is the code:

```
OverlayEntry _createOverlay(Expenses e, BuildContext context) {
  return OverlayEntry(
    builder: (_) => GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _popupDialog.remove(),
      child: BlocProvider<BrowseBloc>.value(
        value: BlocProvider.of(context),
        child: AnimatedDialog(
          child: _createPopupContent(context, e),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

With this change the two methods - edit and delete - work perfectly. Thanks to everyone who replied, I learned something today too!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your widget that you use in `OverlayEntry` in `BlocProvider.value` constructor and pass the needed bloc as an argument to it, like so

```
OverlayEntry _createOverlay(Expenses e, ExampleBloc exampleBloc) {
  return OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _popupDialog.remove(),
      child: BlocProvider<ExampleBloc>.value(
        value: exampleBloc,
        child: AnimatedDialog(
          child: _createPopupContent(context, e),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: why would you create a 2nd provider? Since he is only adding an event, exampleBloc.add(ExampleEvent) would shorten things

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a function and not a widget. So you can either modify _createOverlay to be stateless or stateful widget, or you can pass the bloc as an argument to the function.

In the latter case this would be `_createOverlay(expense, context.read<AppBloc>())`

Comment: Just saw that you flagged the line throwing the error, I thought the issue was somewhere else. But anyway, the answer remains. The issue is that you have declared a function returning a widget and not a widget. Actually it is recommended to use widgets instead of functions, so you may want to transform this into a stateful/less widget

Comment: no, it would not matter if it was a function not a widget class, if it was placed normally in the widget tree inside the blocprovider. the auther is completely right, that overlay behaves differently simply because it is outside the blocprovider context. same would happen if you would try to access blocprovider from a dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that with the overlay. Anyway, solution 2 - passing the bloc as an argument - should work, though, I guess.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, when I'm opening a dialog I have to pass the provider context with BlocProvider.value(). Am i supposed to use a common dialog here too? Is there no other way to pass the bloc provider context to my overlay? To answer @w641, unfortunately passing the bloc as an argument lead to the same error.

Comment: So you had replaced `context.read<BrowseBloc>().add(...)` with `myBlocArgument.add(...)`?

Comment: Yes of course, but as I said I have the same error. I have found the solution, I'm going to post it here in case anyone need it